# Performance of Jquery draggable for 1000s of elements vs re-rendering the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am working on an app which allows an image to be dragged using the draggable utility from Jquery. There are numerous overlay divs associated with the image with many components positioned by pixel location. The numbers could easily be in the 1000s.

Has anyone done the performance numbers on dragging all these elements vs dragging only the image then re-rendering the other elements following the drag?

I'm favoring the later approach but wanted to see if someone has more insight.

---

I ended up going with a single svg layer with the Jquery draggable utility active `$("#zones_imageSVG").draggable( "enable" );` and multiple rect, circles inside. The svg layer drags about easily without lag or skips. This approach circumvents the multiple div layer solution.

```
<svg id="zones_imageSVG" class="moveCursor" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="430" width="549.4444444444445" style="position: relative;">
<image id="zones_image" width="549.4444444444445" height="430" y="0" x="0" xlink:href="./images/testCampus1_HQ_floorA.jpg">
<circle id="icon_sensor0" class="handle_svgAttrCirc" cx="91.63777777777779" cy="287.14444444444445" r="1.9111111111111112" fill="red">
<circle id="icon_sensor1" class="handle_svgAttrCirc" cx="272.0466666666667" cy="332.9155555555556" r="1.9111111111111112" fill="red">
<circle id="icon_sensor2" class="handle_svgAttrCirc" cx="412.60888888888894" cy="221.40222222222224" r="1.9111111111111112" fill="red">
<circle id="icon_sensor3" class="handle_svgAttrCirc" cx="410.3155555555556" cy="103.8688888888889" r="1.9111111111111112" fill="red">
<rect id="idAttrRect0" class="handle_svgAttrRect" x="512.1777777777778" y="73.38666666666667" height="74" width="88" fill="#3196bd">
<rect id="idAttrRect1" class="handle_svgAttrRect" x="416.62222222222226" y="54.27555555555556" height="54" width="48" fill="#3196bd">
<rect id="idAttrRect2" class="handle_svgAttrRect" x="321.0666666666667" y="25.60888888888889" height="24" width="38" fill="#3196bd">
<rect id="idAttrRect3" class="handle_svgAttrRect" x="129.95555555555558" y="44.720000000000006" height="44" width="44" fill="#DC143C">
<rect id="idAttrRect4" class="handle_svgAttrRect" x="416.62222222222226" y="35.16444444444445" height="84" width="38" fill="#A1DC14">
</svg>
```

Comment: And there's some reason you can't create your own perf test? We know very little about what you are trying to do exactly

Comment: It is a general question, not a specific one. I'm looking for points of view. Either technique would work. I could do a test but the whole point is to avoid spending the time on a test if people already have experience in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick sample shows 1000 subitems do not seem to cause issue. Of course, YMMV depending on how complicated your subitems get.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msully725/Lwcdrusb/)

Code to generate sample div:

```
$(function () {
    $(".dragMe").draggable();

    var $dragMe = $(".dragMe.filled");

    var maxTop = 250;
    var maxLeft = 400;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {        
        var $newSubItem = $("<div />")
            .addClass("subItem");

        var randomLeft = Math.random() * maxLeft;
        var randomTop = Math.random() * maxTop;

        $newSubItem.css({
            left: randomLeft,
            top: randomTop
        });

        $dragMe.append($newSubItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the JSFiddle....clearly empty divs drag with no effort. I have run into delays or lags in the past with divs occupied by images. Not certain if the same issues would arise with divs full of svgs. I'll go ahead and incorporate a solution of drag all based on your test and update this question when I know more regarding the impact of images or svgs in the divs on the performance of the drag utility.